# Display sites in my Android app window

Tags: android, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

I want to build an android app, that display web sites, but instead of displaying it in normal browser (e.g. Google chrome), i want to display it in my app window.

I am thinking, for each site, my app will call separate chrome window, so it will open in a chrome, but in my app.

What do you think?

Thanks all for ur help

Comment: You  mean You want to provide a tabbed browsing inside your app

Comment: Thanks Indra for your help.

My app will fetch the site, and display it to the user, so i want the website to be displayed in my app window, not chrome.

Assume, inside my app, we will have icons for CNN, yahoo,.., so once you click it, i want to display the site in my app, not to be run by the default browser.

Thanks again